# Leaflet map with D3.js dynamic graph from geojson data

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json, jquery, d3

I build a `Leaflet` map and display data from a `GeoJSON`. I add a `Leaflet-Sidebar` to my map, and embed the info control inside this sidebar. When a user hovering polygons on the map, raw values are dynamically displayed in the sidebar.

In my `GeoJSON` I also have a field with `JSON` formated values to build a D3 graph. I wan't to add a `D3` graph in the sidebar/info control. Graph will dynamicaly change when user hovering polygons.
Info is an `HTML` structure but `D3` is using `JS` so I don't know how to add a dynamic content. In this case I want to replace `var data` in my graph.html example with props.graph in my map.html.

How can add a `D3` graph in a `Lealflet-Sidebar` with data from my `GeoJSON` ?

**Edit** : [Example 1](http://bl.ocks.org/brandonhaydu/bbac735600b1de910243f41d38857c94), [Example 2](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/11602fac1ea66c2a6d7f78067b2deddb)

**map.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/4.1.0/spin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.Spin/1.1.2/leaflet.spin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/master/src/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/master/src/L.Control.Sidebar.css">    
        <style media="screen">
        #map {width:100%; height:100%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar"><h1>Informations</h1>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="center-objs">               
                    <div id="new-parent">
                    <!-- Graph here -->
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Map -->
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var map = L.map('map').setView([43.446577,6.079717], 9);

                // Baselayer
                var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
                var esri = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}');
                var google = L.tileLayer('http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}');
                var baseLayers = {
                    "Carte OSM": osm,
                    "Photo ESRI": esri,
                    "Google Hybrid": google
                };
                L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
                
                // Style        
                function styleBasique (feature) {
                    return {
                        color: '#5f5f5f',
                        fillOpacity: 0
                    };
                }                   
                
                // Listeners
                function highlightFeature(cadastre) {
                    var cadastreSurvol = cadastre.target;
                    cadastreSurvol.setStyle({
                        color: '#fc0000'
                    });

                    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                        cadastreSurvol.bringToFront(cadastre.target);
                    }
                    info.update(cadastreSurvol.feature.properties);
                }
    
                function resetHighlight(e) {
                    cadastre.resetStyle(e.target);
                    info.update();
                }
                
                // Over
                function onEachFeatureSurvol(feature, layer) {                  
                    layer.on({
                        mouseover: highlightFeature,
                        mouseout: resetHighlight
                    });
                }
                
                // Infos
                var info = L.control({position: 'topleft'});
    
                info.onAdd = function (map) {
                    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                    this.update();
                    return this._div;
                };              
                
                info.update = function (props) {                    
                    this._div.innerHTML = (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.reference_cadastrale + '</b><br><br>'
                    // D3 here ?                        
                    + props.graph
                    : '<i>Move...</i>');
                };              
                info.addTo(map);
    
                //  Container for sidebar
                var htmlObject = info.getContainer();
                var a = document.getElementById('new-parent');
                function setParent(el, newParent) {
                    newParent.appendChild(el);
                }
                setParent(htmlObject, a);

                // Sidebar
                var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
                    closeButton: true,
                    position: 'left'
                });

                map.addControl(sidebar);                
        
                
                // Layer
                
                // JSON
                var dataurl = 'https://carto.cocktaildata.fr/py/parcelles.data.json';

                // Creation
                var cadastre = L.geoJson(false, {
                    //onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeatureSurvol,
                    style: styleBasique
                }).addTo(map);          

                // Spinner
                cadastre.fire('data:loading');

                // Loading data     
                $.getJSON(dataurl, function (data) {

                    // Stop spinner
                    cadastre.fire('data:loaded');

                    // Add data
                    cadastre.addData(data);

                    // Zoom
                    map.fitBounds(cadastre.getBounds());
                    
                    // Sidebar on clic                  
                    cadastre.on('click', function () {
                        sidebar.toggle();
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**graph.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Filiation</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>    
        <style>
            rect {
            fill: #66bfff;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
            .active {
                fill: orange;
                stroke: orange;             
            }
            .activelink {
                fill: none;
                stroke: orange;
                stroke-width: 2.5px;
            }
            .label {
                fill: white;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                pointer-events: none;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            
            .label_date {
                fill: white;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                pointer-events: none;
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #66bfff;
                stroke-width: 2.5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tree"></div>
        <script>
var width = 1000,
    height = 800,
    boxWidth = 150,
    boxHeight = 35,
    gap = {
        width: 50,
        height: 12
    },
    margin = {
        top: 16,
        right: 16,
        bottom: 16,
        left: 16
    },
    svg;

// Data
var data = { 

    "Nodes": [
    {"lvl": 0, "name": "830560000D1980", "date_modification": ""},
    {"lvl":1, "name": "830560000D1954", "date_modification": "2018-08-06"},
    {"lvl":2, "name": "830560000D1586", "date_modification": "2016-05-09"},
    {"lvl":3, "name": "830560000D1582", "date_modification": "1997-10-14"},
    {"lvl":4, "name": "830560000D0239", "date_modification": "1997-06-03"},
    {"lvl":4, "name": "830560000D0240", "date_modification": "1997-06-03"},
    {"lvl":4, "name": "830560000D0241", "date_modification": "1997-06-03"},
    {"lvl":4, "name": "830560000D0246", "date_modification": "1997-06-03"},
    {"lvl":4, "name": "830560000D0247", "date_modification": "1997-06-03"}
    ],
    
    "links": [
    {"source": "830560000D1980", "target": "830560000D1954"},
    {"source": "830560000D1954", "target": "830560000D1586"},
    {"source": "830560000D1586", "target": "830560000D1582"},
    {"source": "830560000D1582", "target": "830560000D0239"},
    {"source": "830560000D1582", "target": "830560000D0240"},
    {"source": "830560000D1582", "target": "830560000D0241"},
    {"source": "830560000D1582", "target": "830560000D0246"},
    {"source": "830560000D1582", "target": "830560000D0247"}
    ] 
};

// Layout
var Nodes = [];
var links = [];
var lvlCount = 0;

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
        "use strict";
        return [d.y, d.x];
    });

function find(text) {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Nodes.length; i += 1) {
        if (Nodes[i].name === text) {
            return Nodes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function mouse_action(val, stat, direction) {
    "use strict";
    d3.select("#" + val.id).classed("active", stat);
    
    links.forEach(function (d) {
        if (direction == "root") {
            if (d.source.id === val.id) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                if (d.target.lvl < val.lvl)
                    mouse_action(d.target, stat, "left");
                else if (d.target.lvl > val.lvl)
                    mouse_action(d.target, stat, "right");
            }
            if (d.target.id === val.id) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                if (direction == "root") {
                    if(d.source.lvl < val.lvl)
                        mouse_action(d.source, stat, "left");
                    else if (d.source.lvl > val.lvl)
                        mouse_action(d.source, stat, "right");
                }
            }
        }else if (direction == "left") {
            if (d.source.id === val.id && d.target.lvl < val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color

                mouse_action(d.target, stat, direction);
            }
            if (d.target.id === val.id && d.source.lvl < val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                mouse_action(d.source, stat, direction);
            }
        }else if (direction == "right") {
            if (d.source.id === val.id && d.target.lvl > val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                mouse_action(d.target, stat, direction);
            }
            if (d.target.id === val.id && d.source.lvl > val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                mouse_action(d.source, stat, direction);
            }
        }
    });
}

function unvisite_links() {
    "use strict";
    links.forEach(function (d) {
        d.visited = false;
    });
}

function renderRelationshipGraph(data) {
    "use strict";
    var count = [];

    data.Nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        count[d.lvl] = 0;
    });
    lvlCount = count.length;

    data.Nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
        d.x = margin.left + d.lvl * (boxWidth + gap.width);
        d.y = margin.top + (boxHeight + gap.height) * count[d.lvl];
        d.id = "n" + i;
        count[d.lvl] += 1;
        Nodes.push(d);
    });

    data.links.forEach(function (d) {
        links.push({
            source: find(d.source),
            target: find(d.target),
            id: "l" + find(d.source).id + find(d.target).id
        });
    });
    unvisite_links();

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes");

    var node = svg.select(".nodes")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(Nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "unit");

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("width", boxWidth)
        .attr("height", boxHeight)
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("rx", 6)
        .attr("ry", 6)
        .on("mouseover", function () {
            mouse_action(d3.select(this).datum(), true, "root");
            unvisite_links();               
            
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            mouse_action(d3.select(this).datum(), false, "root");
            unvisite_links();
        });
        
    // Référence cadastrale
    node.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x + 14; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + 18; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
        
    // Date de modification 
    node.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label_date")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x + 43; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + 30; })
        .text(function (d) {return d.date_modification; });

    links.forEach(function (li) {
        svg.append("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("id", li.id)
            .attr("d", function () {
                var oTarget = {
                    x: li.target.y + 0.5 * boxHeight,
                    y: li.target.x
                };
                var oSource = {
                    x: li.source.y + 0.5 * boxHeight,
                    y: li.source.x
                };
                
                if (oSource.y < oTarget.y) {
                    oSource.y += boxWidth;
                } else {
                    oTarget.y += boxWidth;
                }
                return diagonal({
                    source: oSource,
                    target: oTarget
                });
            });
    });
}

svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g");
    
    renderRelationshipGraph(data);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Mixed files**

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>My Map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/4.1.0/spin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.Spin/1.1.2/leaflet.spin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/master/src/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/master/src/L.Control.Sidebar.css">    
            <style media="screen">
            #map {width:100%; height:100%;}
            rect {
                fill: #66bfff;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .active {
                fill: orange;
                stroke: orange;             
            }
            .activelink {
                fill: none;
                stroke: orange;
                stroke-width: 2.5px;
            }
            .label {
                fill: white;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                pointer-events: none;
                font-size: 16px;
            }           
            .label_date {
                fill: white;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                pointer-events: none;
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #66bfff;
                stroke-width: 2.5px;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
<!- Graph -->
<script>
var width = 1000,
    height = 800,
    boxWidth = 150,
    boxHeight = 35,
    gap = {
        width: 50,
        height: 12
    },
    margin = {
        top: 16,
        right: 16,
        bottom: 16,
        left: 16
    },
    svg;    

// Layout
var Nodes = [];
var links = [];
var lvlCount = 0;

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
        "use strict";
        return [d.y, d.x];
    });

function find(text) {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Nodes.length; i += 1) {
        if (Nodes[i].name === text) {
            return Nodes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function mouse_action(val, stat, direction) {
    "use strict";
    d3.select("#" + val.id).classed("active", stat);
    
    links.forEach(function (d) {
        if (direction == "root") {
            if (d.source.id === val.id) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                if (d.target.lvl < val.lvl)
                    mouse_action(d.target, stat, "left");
                else if (d.target.lvl > val.lvl)
                    mouse_action(d.target, stat, "right");
            }
            if (d.target.id === val.id) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                if (direction == "root") {
                    if(d.source.lvl < val.lvl)
                        mouse_action(d.source, stat, "left");
                    else if (d.source.lvl > val.lvl)
                        mouse_action(d.source, stat, "right");
                }
            }
        }else if (direction == "left") {
            if (d.source.id === val.id && d.target.lvl < val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color

                mouse_action(d.target, stat, direction);
            }
            if (d.target.id === val.id && d.source.lvl < val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                mouse_action(d.source, stat, direction);
            }
        }else if (direction == "right") {
            if (d.source.id === val.id && d.target.lvl > val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                mouse_action(d.target, stat, direction);
            }
            if (d.target.id === val.id && d.source.lvl > val.lvl) {
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("activelink", stat); // change link color
                d3.select("#" + d.id).classed("link", !stat); // change link color
                mouse_action(d.source, stat, direction);
            }
        }
    });
}

function unvisite_links() {
    "use strict";
    links.forEach(function (d) {
        d.visited = false;
    });
}

function renderRelationshipGraph(data) {
    "use strict";
    var count = [];

    data.Nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        count[d.lvl] = 0;
    });
    lvlCount = count.length;

    data.Nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
        d.x = margin.left + d.lvl * (boxWidth + gap.width);
        d.y = margin.top + (boxHeight + gap.height) * count[d.lvl];
        d.id = "n" + i;
        count[d.lvl] += 1;
        Nodes.push(d);
    });

    data.links.forEach(function (d) {
        links.push({
            source: find(d.source),
            target: find(d.target),
            id: "l" + find(d.source).id + find(d.target).id
        });
    });
    unvisite_links();

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes");

    var node = svg.select(".nodes")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(Nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "unit");

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("width", boxWidth)
        .attr("height", boxHeight)
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("rx", 6)
        .attr("ry", 6)
        .on("mouseover", function () {
            mouse_action(d3.select(this).datum(), true, "root");
            unvisite_links();               
            
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            mouse_action(d3.select(this).datum(), false, "root");
            unvisite_links();
        });
        
    // Référence cadastrale
    node.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x + 14; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + 18; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
        
    // Date de modification 
    node.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label_date")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x + 43; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + 30; })
        .text(function (d) {return d.date_modification; });

    links.forEach(function (li) {
        svg.append("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("id", li.id)
            .attr("d", function () {
                var oTarget = {
                    x: li.target.y + 0.5 * boxHeight,
                    y: li.target.x
                };
                var oSource = {
                    x: li.source.y + 0.5 * boxHeight,
                    y: li.source.x
                };
                
                if (oSource.y < oTarget.y) {
                    oSource.y += boxWidth;
                } else {
                    oTarget.y += boxWidth;
                }
                return diagonal({
                    source: oSource,
                    target: oTarget
                });
            });
    });
}

svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g");
    
    // Active in info.update
    //renderRelationshipGraph(data);
        </script>
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar"><h1>Informations</h1>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="center-objs">               
                        <div id="new-parent"></div>
                        <!-- Graph here -->
                        <div id="tree"></div>               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Map -->
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var map = L.map('map').setView([43.446577,6.079717], 9);

                    // Baselayer
                    var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
                    var esri = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}');
                    var google = L.tileLayer('http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}');
                    var baseLayers = {
                        "Carte OSM": osm,
                        "Photo ESRI": esri,
                        "Google Hybrid": google
                    };
                    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
                    
                    // Style        
                    function styleBasique (feature) {
                        return {
                            color: '#5f5f5f',
                            fillOpacity: 0
                        };
                    }                   
                    
                    // Listeners
                    function highlightFeature(cadastre) {
                        var cadastreSurvol = cadastre.target;
                        cadastreSurvol.setStyle({
                            color: '#fc0000'
                        });
    
                        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                            cadastreSurvol.bringToFront(cadastre.target);
                        }
                        info.update(cadastreSurvol.feature.properties);
                    }
        
                    function resetHighlight(e) {
                        cadastre.resetStyle(e.target);
                        info.update();
                    }
                    
                    // Over
                    function onEachFeatureSurvol(feature, layer) {                  
                        layer.on({
                            mouseover: highlightFeature,
                            mouseout: resetHighlight
                        });
                    }
                    
                    // Infos
                    var info = L.control({position: 'topleft'});
        
                    info.onAdd = function (map) {
                        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                        this.update();
                        return this._div;
                    };

                    info.update = function (props) {
                        if (props) {
                            this._div.innerHTML = props.reference_cadastrale;
                            if (props.graph) {
                                eval(props.graph);
                                renderRelationshipGraph(data);
                                document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'none';
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'none';
                            this._div.innerHTML = '<i>Move...</i>';
                        }
                    };

    
                    info.addTo(map);
        
                    //  Container for sidebar
                    var htmlObject = info.getContainer();
                    var a = document.getElementById('new-parent');
                    function setParent(el, newParent) {
                        newParent.appendChild(el);
                    }
                    setParent(htmlObject, a);
    
                    // Sidebar
                    var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
                        closeButton: true,
                        position: 'left'
                    });
    
                    map.addControl(sidebar);                
            
                    
                    // Layer
                    
                    // JSON
                    var dataurl = 'https://carto.cocktaildata.fr/py/parcelles.data.json';
    
                    // Creation
                    var cadastre = L.geoJson(false, {
                        //onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
                        onEachFeature: onEachFeatureSurvol,
                        style: styleBasique
                    }).addTo(map);          
    
                    // Spinner
                    cadastre.fire('data:loading');
    
                    // Loading data     
                    $.getJSON(dataurl, function (data) {
    
                        // Stop spinner
                        cadastre.fire('data:loaded');
    
                        // Add data
                        cadastre.addData(data);
    
                        // Zoom
                        map.fitBounds(cadastre.getBounds());
                        
                        // Sidebar on clic                  
                        cadastre.on('click', function () {
                            sidebar.toggle();
                        });
                    });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: But `graph.html` is complete independent page. How/where do you display it? I don't see any `<iframe>` tag in `map.html`.

Comment: I don't know how to integrate it. I try `<embed>` with `graph.html`, it works with static data but how to dynamically set `var data` ? I think I must mix `map.html` and `graph.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine both pages into one page and then call graph rendering function `renderRelationshipGraph(data)` at the right place with the right data.

First take `<style>` section from `graph.html` and include it in `maps.html`.

Then take `<script>` section from `graph.html`, leaving out `renderRelationshipGraph(data)` call, and include it in `maps.html` before existing code.

Then you need to create a HTML element that will receive graph inside your side bar (with `id='tree'`):

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <h1>Informations</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center-objs">
      <div id="new-parent">
      </div>
      <div id="tree"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All you have to do now is to modify `info.update` function to include call to `renderRelationshipGraph(data)` function. Since actual data for graph in `props.graph` is in the form of JS variable `data` definition, you have to `eval` it before using `data`:

```
info.update = function (props) {
  if (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = props.reference_cadastrale;
    if (props.graph) {
      eval(props.graph);
      renderRelationshipGraph(data);
      document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'block';
      }
    else {
      document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
  else {
    document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'none';
    this._div.innerHTML = '<i>Move...</i>';
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer and explanations. To understand well, what `var data = {...}`; in `graph.html` becomes ? I comment it for the moment because `renderRelationshipGraph(data)` coming after.

Comment: I forgot to mention you have to leave this out also. `var data =` value now comes from `eval(props.graph)`, since `props.graph` contains string `var data = {"Nodes": [ ...`.

Comment: I add this mixed solution in the original post, I can't make it work. Have I missed something ?

Comment: It worked for me. Any errors in the browser debugger console? Any errors in the browser network? For example link `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/master/src/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>` didn't work for me, I had to download it to local server.

Comment: When I inspect code in the browser it returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`in `info.update`.

Comment: Did you include/insert `<div id="tree"></div>` in `<div class="center-objs">`?

Comment: Yes, like you said before `<div id="sidebar"><h1>Informations</h1><div class="container"><div class="center-objs"><div id="new-parent"></div><div id="tree"></div></div></div></div>`

Comment: Then `document.getElementById('tree')` shouldn't return `null` value.

Comment: I think so, Something else is wrong in my syntax. I try to found a solution and get the post informed.

Comment: I can display chart in the sidebar when the user over o polygon know but charts appends to each other. It seems `document.getElementById('tree').style.display = 'none';` isn't effective. Div `id='tree'` must 'reset' at each mouse out where are agree ?

Comment: Ok I got it : I need to execute a `d3.selectAll("#tree > *").remove();` at the beginning of `renderRelationshipGraph(data)` to clear the div from previous overed data. Thanks a lot for your help.